# PrestaShop Multistore API not working for additional stores

Tags: prestashop

I have found this weird issue where the webservice API works correctly for the main store, but it redirects to a 404 for any added store (multistore configuration).

Anybody has any idea about it?

PrestaShop version 1.6.1.19
Theme Warehouse

The multistore is being tested on a staging site, so maybe that has something to do with it.